# Ckeditor files included by script with wrong url

Tags: ckeditor

I have a simple page and used ckeditor that works just fine on the localhost but when I publish to Azure it doesn't work anymore...

The code:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                  "~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
                  ));
```

and the View:

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Index</h2>


<div class='description'>
    <p>
    This editor is using an <code>&lt;iframe&gt;</code> element-based editing area, provided by the <strong>Wysiwygarea</strong> plugin.
</p>
</div>
<textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        // This call can be placed at any point after the
        // <textarea>, or inside a <head><script> in a
        // window.onload event handler.

        // Replace the <textarea id="editor"> with an CKEditor
        // instance, using default configurations.

        CKEDITOR.replace("editor1");
    });

    </script>}
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</p>
```

I got a few errors to the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)        /config.js?t=DBAA
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /skins/moono/editor.css?t=DBAA
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /lang/ro.js?t=DBAA
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined
```

Answer (score 16):

I think that setting [`CKEDITOR.basePath`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-basePath) should do the trick for you.

Comment: Eureka, it Works :D
(not sure, why we need to set this though to work)

Comment: Setting `CKEDITOR.basePath` after editor initialization appears to incompletely set the path as some plugins still tried to use the wrong path.  The more complete solution as actually mentioned in the linked documentation and here by @Santanu Nandi is to set `window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` prior to loading ckeditor.js.

Comment: user650881 you are right. CKEDITOR.basePath does not work for some plugins. Setting window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH is the proper solution.

Answer (score 7):

Set window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH properly, like 
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'http://localhost/public/resources/ckeditor/';

window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH should have the proper path of the ckeditor folder which contains plugins,skins and other folders, js files with utility functions.

window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH will set CKEDITOR.basePath autometically.

Try to set window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH before requiring ckeditor.js

Comment: I am loading CKE with requirejs and this is the only way I could get it to work after optimisation (r.js).  I put the code recommended here in the `main` script, before the `ckeditor` module is ever required, and it is working correctly.  Setting `CKEDITOR.basePath` in the shim config seemed to work initially, but for some reason it failed for scripts loaded dynamically through user interaction (e.g. link editor dialog).

Comment: I'm having this problem now, and this doesn't solve my problem. This is my line `CKEDITOR.basePath = '/lib/ckeditor/';`another solution?

Comment: @amurcia don't set CKEDITOR.basePath.
Set window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH='/lib/ckeditor/'; before requiring ckeditor.js, it'll automatically adjust   CKEDITOR.basePath