# ckeditor.js:228 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined in CKEDITOR5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using ckeditor5 and It is working fine in one page of my project but the problem is when I point/redirect the page from another application then it through an uncatch exception

Please suggest me how can I resolve this problem.

Here is the exception:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ():8080/demo/ckeditor5/config.js?t=G2VC:1 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ():8080/demo/ckeditor5/lang/en.js?t=G2VC:1 

ckeditor.js:228 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined
    at Object.d (ckeditor.js:228)
    at f (ckeditor.js:229)
    at Array.x (ckeditor.js:229)
    at A (ckeditor.js:229)
    at HTMLScriptElement.CKEDITOR.env.ie.CKEDITOR.env.version.g.$.onerror (ckeditor.js:230)
```

and when I type someting in the textarea then it through another error like below image:
[image: issue]

Answer (score 0):

**config.js** is not being loaded because of not correct path. apparently that's the cause of this error.

I think you have to set base path in setting: `CKEDITOR.basePath`

Might be you have same issue: [Ckeditor files included by script with wrong url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180925/ckeditor-files-included-by-script-with-wrong-url)

Comment: I have added this code befor load the ckeditor script but still same issue<script type="text/javascript">
  window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '../js/ckeditor5/';
 </script>

Comment: As per previous thread, you have to Set window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH='/lib/ckeditor/'; before requiring ckeditor.js, it'll automatically adjust CKEDITOR.basePath